# How to unlink a file based on ip address (using gethostbyaddr method)

Tags: php

I am using gethostbyaddr method to get actual path as follows(The number below are not actual one. i am giving only sample)

```
$ip =  "162.11.11.111";
$host = gethostbyaddr( $ip );
```

Using this $host variable, I construct whole path of the file as below

```
$dirAd = "//".$host. "/temp/user/sample/Test 1/Active.xls";
```

If i echo $dirAd variable, it is giving me a string. example as below

```
//xxx-xxxsvr01.xxx-gg.com/temp/user/sample/Test 1/Active.xls
```

Using this $dirAd, I am trying to unlink(delete) the file Active.xls as below

```
unlink($dirAd);
```

But it is always showing error

```
Warning: unlink(//xxx-xxxsvr01.xxx-gg.com/temp/user/sample/Test 1/Active.xls): Resource temporarily unavailable
```

After trying many methods, found out that this error is caused by the two back slashes at the beginning of $dirAd. If I removed those //, no more error. But since path is not valid, it won't delete away any files. Does anyone know how to delete a file with an ipaddress included in path using php?

Comment: That's a URL, not a filename. Are you really trying to delete a file on a remote webserver?

Comment: Hi Barmar, yes. I need to delete the file named Active.xls from the webserver //xxx-xxxsvr01.xxx-gg.com

Comment: It's unlikely that the webserver allows deletions, particularly without authentication. You probably need to access it using FTP.

Comment: Okay...I never used FTP in PHP before. So I need to make an FTP connection to the server and then only can delete the file; Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, see the `ftp_delete()` function.